# Can i use a 'for' loop,range function and an initially empty array to make an output array having all elements in range in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I want to make an array of a range of numbers. and i tried the following method:

```
set1=[]
for x in range(4,100,4):
 set1.append(x)
 print(set1)
```

but this printed all the arrays starting from [4,8] , [4,8,12].. and so on.
i just want the final array as the output.

Comment: Due to poor indentation, it's hard to tell what is inside of what in your code. If you're printing in the loop though, just print after the loop. Please fix your indentation.

Comment: A1 and then set1? Add full code.

Comment: sorry for the mistakes i made. i corrected the code in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set1=[]
for x in range(4,100,4):
 set1.append(x)
print(set1)
```

print statement must be outside the for loop or else it'll print after every iteration, as seen in the output you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeatedly print the `set1` list, don't do your `print` calls in the loop. If you unindent the line the `print` call is on it will happen just once, after the loop ends:

```
set1=[]
for x in range(4,100,4):
    set1.append(x)
print(set1)
```